# Why does y=0 does not stick the svg-circle to the top when viewBox starts at 0

Tags: svg, viewbox

It basically have a small html-file which contains this html:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 15">
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="5" fill="black"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="400" y1="0" y2="0" stroke="black">
</svg>

<style>
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  background: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Yet the output looks like this:
[image]

I would have expected the line and the center of the circle to stick to the top. As the y-coordinates are 0 in a coordinate space that starts at 0 as defined in the `viewBox=0 0 400 15`.

What am I missing here?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  background: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 15">
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="5" fill="black"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="400" y1="0" y2="0" stroke="black">
</svg>
```

Comment: In the CSS you are not preserving the aspect ratio of the viewBox thus forcing scaling. The default for the [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) is `xMidYMid`. This is aligning the midpoint X value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint X value of the viewport. Also is aligning the midpoint Y value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint Y value of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I can't create an arbitrary Coordinate system with these 4 values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the `viewBox` (the area of the SVG canvas to be rendered) and the viewport (the area it is rendered into, defined by CSS `width` and `height`) do not match. In this case, the attribute [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) decides where the canvas is positioned and at what size.

The default value, if the attribute is missing, is `"xMidYMid meet"`, which means: place it into the middle at maximum size that fits. To move it to the top of the viewport, set `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  background: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 15" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet">
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="5" fill="black"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="400" y1="0" y2="0" stroke="black">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a great question. And it looks like it is fixed to the top. But the SVG has qualities to make it responsive and center itself full screen.

```css
    svg {
      background: gray;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

The above CSS along with the missing height and width attribute allow the SVG to scale. And it's being told to consume all available width and height which causes it to center. Removing the CSS fixes the elements at the top of the screen.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 15">
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="5" fill="black"/>
  <line x1="0" x2="400" y1="0" y2="0" stroke="black">
</svg>
```